# Find $x$ such that $Ax = Ab$ when $A$ is not invertible and $x \neq b$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, optimization, systems-of-equations, inverse

I was wondering if it is possible to solve this equation using some smart trick (rather than simply denoting $d = Ab$ and solving the system as usual) since it looks very symmetric.
$$
Ax = Ab
$$
for some known matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, some known vector $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and an unknown vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Importantly I would like $x \neq b$.

##### Bonus

I am asking this question because I need to solve
$$
(I - cc^\top)x = (I - cc^\top)b
$$
for known vectors $c$ and $b$, with $c$ a unit vector.

Comment: take any element $y \in \ker(A)$ and set $x = b+y$. Then you have $$Ax =A(b+y) = Ab + Ay =Ab $$

Comment: Why not just take $x=b$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor forgot to say that, I want to find solutions other than that

Comment: Well then you’ve completely used up your symmetry I think. Note that if your right hand side is not of the form $Ab$ then you just can’t solve the problem

Comment: In your case, the kernel are vectors that are multiple to c, If not invertible. Note also your matrix is invertible If norm c is not one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $y$ is a solution of $Ay=0$ then $x=y+b$

Comment: Would solving the system like this generally be faster than solving the system $Ax = d$ for $d=Ab$?

Comment: What do you mean with faster? For a computer it is in both cases a linear system of the same size, so it does not make a difference.

Comment: you can save the time to calculate $Ab$.